# Wrong number of rows when reading a CSV file

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, read.table

I have a CSV file that I wrote with a Perl script. Files opens fine in Excel or in Simple Text and looks fine. It has 9 rows. However, when I count it with nrow() or dim(), I get 8 rows. This is causing downstream problems. Headers are 'a' to 'j'. Thanks.

```
a   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
b   0.401374    0.467736    0.582949    0.751601    0.860567    0.967758    0.965143    0.961866    0.863406    0.914746    0.984586    0.950531    0.935572    0.949083    0.968802    0.958067    0.980222    0.9917  1.009155    1.013709    1.008558    0.99945 0.988164    0.976623    0.973183    0.96519 0.968162    0.966721    0.962864    0.965214    0.968562    0.97235 0.981299    0.99698 1.013786    1.033542    1.050533    1.060338    1.072083    1.067729    1.057589    1.053562    1.030205    1.013217    0.994013    0.986159    0.981776    0.974559    0.975097    0.969779    0.969334    0.960085    0.963134    0.963621    0.961985    0.963223    0.957363    0.980404    0.962947    0.974328    0.969675    0.976323    0.974097    0.966781    0.972603    0.962981    0.975821    0.958069    0.980906    0.975684    0.943835    0.948154    0.94311 0.942586    1.022319    1.009415    1.021423    1.059047    1.085726    1.010326    1.036282    1.057417    1.046533    1.159883    1.204652    1.151679    1.244229    1.301202    1.490301    1.304381    1.712297    1.348033    0.736757    0.640583    1.474143    5.664327    2.547607    9.543845    9.572942    4.721692    0
c   0.483217    0.29612 0.31702 0.543388    0.691817    0.734183    0.772058    0.881707    0.942905    0.921662    0.970798    0.953243    0.945404    1.019665    0.938993    0.971219    0.959108    0.987285    0.991304    1.027208    0.994463    0.984487    0.998657    0.978592    0.96603 0.961446    0.957071    0.955184    0.957707    0.954644    0.970809    0.962456    0.973713    0.991673    1.012059    1.029588    1.042737    1.06048 1.065989    1.07043 1.060842    1.046754    1.035313    1.01837 0.998625    0.985907    0.981162    0.979541    0.977763    0.976078    0.968934    0.968159    0.967233    0.97003 0.969417    0.973832    0.973617    0.984223    0.976866    0.979505    0.985046    0.977616    0.987978    0.976532    0.974292    0.982313    0.975786    0.972815    1.004171    0.974393    0.977434    0.9359  0.960213    0.985705    1.020929    1.011589    1.006536    0.988384    1.037618    1.004525    1.0499  1.075382    1.126694    1.097262    1.145451    1.138151    1.268054    1.364637    1.548332    1.784365    1.66168 1.857999    1.281119    0.714744    1.409833    5.417217    2.436466    15.516732   14.648507   4.515705    0
d   0.54739 0.417737    0.560592    0.762408    0.840282    0.906248    0.970471    0.949707    0.933483    0.934403    1.07911 0.96818 1.019784    0.984101    0.96848 0.962378    0.981269    1.010261    1.036639    1.020298    0.996359    1.002746    0.986174    0.987546    0.975991    0.963343    0.967528    0.968886    0.967459    0.962992    0.966011    0.973625    0.982147    0.995917    1.010114    1.029   1.04789 1.059755    1.07154 1.072574    1.060199    1.052861    1.040088    1.017165    0.996716    0.989731    0.970404    0.974642    0.970293    0.967025    0.964511    0.962078    0.966636    0.960035    0.957345    0.967206    0.964344    0.972463    0.970353    0.971953    0.965436    0.968887    0.979595    0.967244    0.978083    0.956349    0.976509    0.990198    0.967315    0.965619    0.937825    0.963115    0.937972    0.940783    0.950582    0.999596    0.964397    1.073948    1.011812    0.992207    0.968892    1.019393    1.036893    1.040682    1.136172    1.175936    1.370799    1.626169    1.540309    1.521391    1.696523    1.335615    1.526301    0.740462    2.008275    3.367288    3.155172    17.020668   5.690853    9.356391    0
e   0.534257    0.623387    0.658379    1.021547    1.086113    1.10879 1.092341    1.047527    0.978066    1.113138    1.097839    1.081836    1.061449    1.01633 0.977861    1.064722    0.993365    1.099759    1.082891    1.097126    1.068604    1.050802    1.035536    1.020507    1.005109    1.010964    1.00586 0.999783    0.998753    0.995041    0.991949    0.991496    0.99574 1.009774    1.028723    1.05391 1.05445 1.076628    1.073423    1.073404    1.061363    1.047512    1.033238    1.004406    0.996751    0.969424    0.958341    0.960392    0.945673    0.947249    0.95037 0.943966    0.933722    0.930457    0.930735    0.925822    0.932857    0.93624 0.926209    0.926974    0.921879    0.92411 0.938514    0.936167    0.946051    0.938521    0.91792 0.927171    0.927905    0.930573    0.941126    0.905906    0.885595    0.890934    0.956747    0.993943    1.004912    0.966991    1.029596    0.934891    0.902882    1.005912    1.055131    1.060036    1.210456    1.204307    1.363757    1.383982    1.301273    1.834122    2.071989    1.468085    2.066713    1.317749    1.516236    7.76809 3.930527    17.669452   11.815548   0   0
f   0.580985    0.297751    0.444868    0.651545    0.850767    0.88177 1.045047    1.069708    1.007082    0.970515    0.995463    1.077379    0.956378    0.9633  0.963782    0.972252    1.001651    1.012825    1.024981    1.039174    1.018857    1.014041    1.004354    0.982018    0.985064    0.985249    0.976443    0.974376    0.972889    0.971678    0.975724    0.976216    0.984206    0.996217    1.017416    1.036441    1.049075    1.06143 1.068939    1.070938    1.062538    1.047006    1.032694    1.014813    0.99588 0.979417    0.969517    0.974295    0.968714    0.964257    0.964937    0.959818    0.956047    0.95799 0.95596 0.950887    0.954934    0.958854    0.961795    0.962765    0.970278    0.96375 0.963601    0.961951    0.956463    0.963495    0.957578    0.955705    0.988666    0.975476    0.967505    0.956554    0.927677    0.955343    0.973189    1.010146    1.057061    0.998942    1.042087    1.069688    1.010457    1.050207    1.037386    1.131603    1.180845    1.164758    1.302756    1.670756    1.413374    1.596161    1.643926    1.543092    0.756803    0.536158    1.850752    6.163239    0.799615    9.58566 14.422327   0   0
g   0.368286    0.133209    0.189854    0.329541    0.312233    0.371553    0.55966 0.663372    0.678283    0.811317    0.896647    0.887872    0.919798    0.945003    0.895565    0.968837    0.991214    0.987583    1.00316 1.020707    1.015521    0.985502    0.998961    0.976184    0.98338 0.973889    0.9674  0.968549    0.966232    0.966105    0.966297    0.965883    0.976568    0.999395    1.011924    1.03344 1.051626    1.059014    1.063355    1.068936    1.053488    1.045903    1.031994    1.008174    0.991796    0.972343    0.973369    0.969431    0.967085    0.963154    0.966865    0.962234    0.95759 0.96642 0.966713    0.974709    0.973966    0.981547    0.984093    0.991954    0.985628    0.996822    0.991295    0.98659 0.989936    0.978239    0.977446    1.025974    1.042636    1.040808    0.982495    0.991225    1.015466    1.008242    1.030642    1.004306    1.086892    1.097275    1.120253    1.138095    1.135337    1.209962    1.225443    1.224011    1.338381    1.450842    1.727673    1.719172    1.82727 2.074713    1.709345    2.290568    2.321692    1.542005    0.798422    8.181066    2.759658    5.513723    22.122134   13.63921    2.675538
h   0.30497 0.32974 0.424478    0.455078    0.523571    0.606559    0.660406    0.703971    0.729999    0.915297    0.981265    0.96674 0.925204    1.036524    0.953261    0.978409    0.987847    1.01834 1.019895    1.038827    1.024035    1.012836    0.994345    0.994459    0.972257    0.97309 0.978206    0.968312    0.964948    0.962225    0.96529 0.974432    0.975632    0.994073    1.010742    1.030179    1.042012    1.056884    1.058926    1.060281    1.059781    1.038339    1.029365    1.009022    0.986078    0.978875    0.9716  0.969215    0.958117    0.972496    0.968037    0.97107 0.958519    0.970863    0.969962    0.975005    0.978711    0.984085    0.984683    0.984162    0.996244    0.997889    0.994661    1.001441    0.985552    1.021569    1.000549    1.002552    0.997683    1.033186    1.013344    1.019947    1.057587    1.033291    1.069199    1.036226    1.168877    1.175308    1.22975 1.11576 1.122753    1.106146    1.224346    1.258167    1.290459    1.477277    1.427201    1.742816    1.558004    1.386269    1.910887    1.920479    1.08143 1.206672    2.082642    3.048554    3.085038    18.491473   12.365233   0   0
j   0.354463    0.327358    0.398802    0.473   0.602168    0.764142    0.819362    0.914898    0.823412    1.010715    0.854421    0.892255    0.981967    0.966507    1.021983    0.975027    0.961088    0.960516    0.971975    1.01222 0.979767    0.987716    0.98707 0.970561    0.963265    0.962699    0.958097    0.961291    0.952577    0.958112    0.9596  0.967041    0.97311 0.991703    1.006086    1.025563    1.040921    1.055595    1.05902 1.068992    1.060288    1.046614    1.037744    1.019254    0.996458    0.984552    0.986514    0.984358    0.977773    0.980087    0.972711    0.969122    0.975125    0.968046    0.968058    0.979439    0.97843 0.978518    0.98551 0.979352    0.983617    0.984822    0.986629    0.986932    0.991861    1.002382    0.999269    0.99465 0.994519    0.987402    1.000541    0.977929    0.976282    0.964102    1.032155    1.04334 1.063832    1.096302    1.105991    1.065358    1.106644    1.068104    1.064264    1.167453    1.278531    1.383359    1.417057    1.672739    1.39427 1.396529    1.94346 1.50906 1.274638    1.467406    2.337833    6.387922    0   11.099379   16.193772   4.992065    0
```

Comment: See `header` under `?read.csv`.

Comment: You have failed to provide any useful information about the file in question, or the code used to read it into R. Which is weird, because based on your description, the entire file could simply be pasted into your question.

Comment: added the file "joran".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in `R` can have default values for some parameters. For `read.csv`:

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
         dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)
```

`header=TRUE` means que first row is assume to be the header of the file. This means, it won't be recognized as data by R. If you read your file with `header=FALSE`

```
read.csv(file, header=FALSE)
```

you will get the 9 rows.